# How do I replace sequences of whitespaces by one space but don't trim in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, removing-whitespace

The function `normalize-space` removes leading and trailing whitespace and replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space. How can I **only** replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space in XSLT 1.0? For instance `"..x.y...\n\t..z."` (spaces replaced by a dot for readability) should become `".x.y.z."`.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath 1.0 expression -- solution (and of course, this is also an XSLT 1.0 solution, too). :) No extension functions needed/used.

Comment: Check my answer for a three function calls solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without Becker's method, you could use some [discouraged](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) character as mark:

```
translate(normalize-space(concat('&#x7F;',.,'&#x7F;')),'&#x7F;','')
```

**Note**: Three function calls...

Or with any character but repeating some expression:

```
substring(
   normalize-space(concat('.',.,'.')),
   2,
   string-length(normalize-space(concat('.',.,'.'))) - 2
)
```

In XSLT you can easily declare a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="vNormalize" select="normalize-space(concat('.',.,'.'))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="susbtring($vNormalize,2,string-length($vNormalize)-2)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, the use of discouraged characters is a clever trick. You only forgot the `;` after each character entity (or it got lost when editing).

Comment: @Jakob: You are welcome. Also you are correct: I've forgotten last `;` in entities. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
concat(substring(' ', 1 + not(substring(.,1,1)=' ')), 
       normalize-space(), 
       substring(' ', 1 + not(substring(., string-length(.)) = ' '))
      )
```

**To verify this, the following transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring(' ', 1 + not(substring(.,1,1)=' ')),
          normalize-space(),
          substring(' ', 1 + not(substring(., string-length(.)) = ' '))
          )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document:**

```
<t>
 <t1>   xxx   yyy   zzz   </t1>
 <t2>xxx   yyy   zzz</t2>
 <t3>  xxx   yyy   zzz</t3>
 <t4>xxx   yyy   zzz  </t4>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <t1> xxx yyy zzz </t1>
   <t2>xxx yyy zzz</t2>
   <t3> xxx yyy zzz</t3>
   <t4>xxx yyy zzz </t4>
</t>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll use Alejandro's method although it relies of data that does not contain a special character. Both answers are helpful :-)

Comment: @Jacob: You are welcome. I guess that you chose @Alejandro's answer because he split the expression into variables and thus made it more understandable. You may be aware that among ourselves we pride in providing one-liner XPath solutions :)

Comment: I must admit that in doubt I choose the answer from the user with less reputation (if there are multiple equal answers), just to narrow the gap ;-) XPath is great. If only XSLT would have a more readable syntax, similar to XPath!!

Comment: @Jacob: In XSLT 2.0 one can code almost completely in XPath 2.0 - only. Even better in XSLT 3.0.