# Normalize space issue with html tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here's one for you XSLT gurus :-)

I have to deal with XML output from a Java program I cannot control.

In the docs outputted by this app the html tags remain as

```
<u><i><b><em>
```

etc,  instead of

```
&lt;u&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;em&gt; and so on.
```

That's not a massive problem, I use XSLT to fix that, but using normalize-space to remove excess whitespace also removes spaces before these html tags.

Example

```
<Locator Precode="7">
<Text LanguageId="7">The next word is <b>bold</b> and is correctly spaced 
around the html tag,
but the sentence has extra whitespace and 
line breaks</Text>
</Locator>
```

If I run the XSLT script we use to remove extra white space, of which this is the relevant part

```
<xsl:template match="text(.)">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In the resulting output the xslt has correctly removed the extra whitespace and the line breaks, but it has also removed the space before the  tag resulting in this output :-

```
The next word isboldand is correctly spaced around the html tag, but the sentence has extra whitespace and line breaks.
```

The spacing before and after the word "bold" has been stripped as well.

Anyone have any ideas how to prevent this from happening? Pretty well at my wits end so any help will be greatly appreciated!

:-)

Hi again,

Yes of course, here's the full stylesheet. We have to deal with the html tags and spacing in one pass

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Text//*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Instruction//*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Title//*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What processor and version of XSLT are you working with? Also, please provide a full stylesheet. Finally, arguments are not allowed inside `text()`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Using your full stylesheet, in the output only the tags `<b>` and `</b>` are escaped. Why is that? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT 1.0 solution is an XPath expression to replace a sequence of several whitespace characters with a single one. The idea is *not* my own, it is taken from [an answer by Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037951/1987598).

The advantage over the built-in `normalize-space()` function is that trailing whitespace (in your case, before and after the `b` element) is kept.

**EDIT**: As a response to you editing your question. Below is the said XPath expression incorporated into your stylesheet. Also:

- Explicitly saying `omit-xml-declaration="no"` is redundant. It is the default action taken by the XSLT processor
- Several of your templates have the same content. I summarized them using `|` to a single one.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  


<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy> 
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Text//*|Instruction//*|Title//*">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;')" />
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring(' ', 1 + not(substring(.,1,1)=' ')),
          normalize-space(),
          substring(' ', 1 + not(substring(., string-length(.)) = ' '))
          )
  "/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Locator Precode="7">
   <Text LanguageId="7">The next word is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; and is correctly spaced around the html tag, but the sentence has extra whitespace and line breaks</Text>
</Locator>
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for the quick reply.  Sadly that solution won't work in this situation it seems.  I need to output XML still, and although the above method works in text mode it does not solve the issue for output method=xml.

Comment: @user3012857 That's why we need you to show a full stylesheet, not only a snippet. From your question one could assume that you are only outputting text. This also works when `<xsl:output method="xml"`, see http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHW/2.

Comment: I have added the full stylesheet above. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @user3012857 Edited my answer, and added a question as a comment under your question. Have a look.

Comment: Mathias you are a giant amongst men. Looks like it does the trick and thank you for pointing out the shortened version of the template match too.