# XSL normalize-space() is too greedy around embedded tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I thought this would be simple. Here's my input. I don't have any control over its layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic>
    <title>The Torments of Hell</title>
    <body>
        <p>Life is a <xref href="dungeon.xml">dungeon
            </xref> and
            an <xref href="abyss.xml">abyss</xref>.
        </p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

The output I'm trying to get:

```
...
Life is a<ref>[[dungeon|dungeon.xml]]</ref> and an <ref>[[abyss|abyss.xml]]</ref>.
...
```

So the WYSIWYG (the output of a different tool, over which I have no control, and which converts `ref` tags to footnotes with citations) would look like this:

Life is a dungeon<sup>1</sup> and an abyss<sup>2</sup>.

Here's the xsl I started with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="topic">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="body/p"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xref">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;ref&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>[[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
        <xsl:text>]]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/ref&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's the output I got:

```
...
Life is a <ref>[[dungeon|dungeon.xml]]</ref> and
            an <ref>[[abyss|abyss.xml]]</ref>.
...
```

No problem, I'll just use `normalize-space` to get rid of the line breaks:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now my output looks like this:

```
...
Life is a<ref>[[dungeon|dungeon.xml]]</ref>and an<ref>[[abyss|abyss.xml]]</ref>.
...
```

And my WYSIWYG looks like this:

Life is adungeon<sup>1</sup>and anabyss<sup>2</sup>.

The linefeed is gone, but so are the spaces both before and after the `ref` tags; these I would like to have kept. I could just hack it and add a space before and after my `ref` tags, but then I get this ugliness:

Life is a dungeon<sup>1</sup> and an abyss<sup>2</sup> .

Notice the space between *abyss* and the period. I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037951/1987598) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530078/normalize-space-issue-with-html-tags), but those eliminate only extra spaces; they don't help with linefeeds.

I spent all day trying to do this with XSL, with no luck. Then I spent 45 minutes writing a javascript that does exactly what I want. The practical, immediate problem solved, but it seems strange to me that this would be so difficult with XSL. It seems so simple. Is there a way to do this with XSL, or do I need to preprocess the XML before I apply the stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you are using XSLT version 2.0 you can use regular expressions with the `replace` function to get the "squash runs of whitespace down to a single space" part of the `normalize-space()` behaviour without also getting the "and trim leading and trailing whitespace" part.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\s+', ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will squash leading and/or trailing runs of whitespace down to a single space (as with any run of internal whitespace) but won't remove them entirely.

As an aside, you don't need to use `disable-output-escaping` for the `ref` tags, as they are properly balanced inside the template.  Just

```
<xsl:template match="xref">
    <ref>
        <xsl:text>[[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><!-- or <apply-templates/> -->
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
        <xsl:text>]]</xsl:text>
    </ref>
</xsl:template>
```

will work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great. And the escaping thing too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the linefeed using template match without the `normalize-space` function, here an example :

```
<xsl:template match="yourText">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string, '&#10;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '&#10;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This will remove all occurence of `newline` in your text.

**Edit** : Then you could call the `normalize-space` function on the result to get rid of the extra spaces.